# Stretching horizontal divs (middle div stretches)

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a header that streatches with the page width.

My header consists of three parts, two sides with fixed width and the middle that stretches.

```
<div class="bigBlueBox">
   <div class="headerBox">
       <div class="leftSide"></div>
       <div class="middleSide"></div>
       <div class="rightSide"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I use `display: box` and `box-flex: 1` for the stretching of the middle box.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.bigBlueBox {
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.headerBox {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: -moz-box;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 45px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.leftSide {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 45px;
    width: 20px;
}
.middleSide {
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 45px;
}
.rightSide {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 45px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

My problem is that, as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYuAz/), there's a margin I can't get rid of (the red border is not around the blue box).

[image]

How can I remove this "margin" ?

Otherwise, is there another way to do it without using boxes ?

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution was very simple, I just had to add some content inside the middle div:

```
<div class="bigBlueBox">
    <div class="headerBox">
        <div class="leftSide"></div>
        <div class="middleSide"> SOMETHING  </div>
        <div class="rightSide"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Which could also be `&nbsp;`